# String shows twice in applet

Tags: java, applet

My string "What was the sequence?"  appears twice at an interval of about 3 seconds , dunno why...after i hit the button restartBtn. Anybody any idea why?Thank you.

```
if (level > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 800,800);
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor( Color.black);
    g.drawString("What was the sequence?",150,300);
}

if (source == restartBtn) {
    randomize();
    nextBtn.setVisible(true);                  
    restartBtn.setVisible(false); 
    exitBtn.setVisible(false);    
    repaint();      
}
```

Comment: Add more detail to the code in the question. We need to know the name of this function, and where/how it is called.

Comment: sorry guys I realised what my problem was .I never cleared the screen after my last level so whenever i restarted from level 1 my previous image would still have been there. thanks